# Swiper slider некорректно отображается при изменении ширины экрана

Tags: html, css, jquery, swiper

Использую в проекте Swiper
Most Modern Mobile Touch Slider ver. 4.4.6. Дизайн адаптивный соответственно в коде инициализации слайдера прописаны breackpoints.

Но при смене размера экрана параметры из breackpoints применяются не все, что приводит к некорректному отображению слайдера. Но если перезагрузить страницу слайдер отображается как нужно. Документацию прочитана от и до, что я упустил? Как решить данный баг?

Ссылка на страницу - [Нажимай](http://ci31980.tmweb.ru/forstack/main.html) Слайдер находится на втором экране и на разрешениях выше 1260 он статичен так как всего 3 карточки курсов.

Пример кода:

```
    var scrollSwiper = new Swiper('.scroll-swiper', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        slidesPerColumn: 1,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        observeSlideChildren: true,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 2500,
        },
        breakpoints: {
            767: {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                freeMode: true,
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                allowTouchMove: true,
                scrollbar: {
                    el: '.scroll-swiper-scrollbar',
                    hide: true,
                },
            },
            1024: { 
                allowTouchMove: true,
            },
            1260: {
                allowTouchMove: true,
                spaceBetween: 15,
                slidesPerView: 2,
                slidesPerColumn: 2,
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: При изменении экрана на брейкпоинте делайте `scrollSwiper.update();`

Comment: scrollSwiper.update(); Данный вариант пробовал первым делом. Использую данную функцию
                                                                                   
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    scrollSwiper.update();
 });

Результат не изменился

Answer (score 0):

Слайдер ломается потому, что используется breakpoints в сочетании с slidesPerColumn, а этого делать нельзя. Документация слайдера: https://idangero.us/swiper/api/
Лучше в карточках-слайдах делать вертикальную компоновку (портретный вид) для узких экранов - адаптив контента самих слайдов.

> **breakpoints** (object) Allows to set different parameter for different responsive breakpoints (screen sizes). Not all parameters
>   can be changed in breakpoints, only those which are not required
>   different layout and logic, like slidesPerView, slidesPerGroup,
>   spaceBetween. **Such parameters like slidesPerColumn, loop, direction,
>   effect won't work**!